# raycast doesn't work with prefabs in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity, and I'm having problem with the use of Raycast on Prefabs.
More specifically, what I'm trying to do is spawn randomically 10 prefabs with a script A, then I use a script B where I use a Raycast to hit these objects.
The script A and the script B use a SerializeField with the same prefab to know which object to spawn (script A) and which object hit (script B).
The problem is that the Raycast doesn't recognize the instantiation as the GameObject assigned in the SerializeField, so when I hit the instantiation nothing happen.
My code is:

Script A

```
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject coin, floor, house;
 
    public GameObject mushSpawn;
 
    Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
 
    public GameObject coinInstance;
 
 
 
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 center = floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.center;
        Vector3 size = floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size;
 
        Vector3 centerHouse = house.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.center;
        Vector3 sizeHouse = house.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size;
 
        float posX = (center.x - (size.x / 2)) + 2;
        float posZ = (center.z - (size.z / 2)) + 2;
 
        float posHouseX = (centerHouse.x - (sizeHouse.x / 2));
        float posHouseZ = (centerHouse.z - (sizeHouse.z / 2));
 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(posXSpawn, 0.0f, posZSpawn);
                mushSpawn = Instantiate(coin, position, rot) as GameObject;
            }
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

Script B

```
public class GazeSysten : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject coin, buttonMove, buttonTake, pointer, floor, buttonEnding;
    public Camera cam;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Color active = Color.green;
    private Color noActive = Color.red;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = noActive;
        position = this.transform.position;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position = position;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray lastPosition = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(lastPosition, out hit))
        {
            pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = active;
        }
        else
        {
            pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = noActive;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(Physics.Raycast(lastPosition, out hit))
            {
                    if(hit.transform.gameObject == coin)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Is a coin");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

If in the scene I drag the instantiated object in the SerializeObject slot of script B the code works, someone can help me?

Comment: What you suggest to do in this case? How can I access to the instances?

Comment: (The double raycast is my error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instances (clones) of the `coin` prefab != the `coin` prefab reference itself. They simply are not equal but two different objects...

Rather give it either a [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) and check [`hit.gameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html)

```
if (Physics.Raycast(lastPosition, out hit))
{
    pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = active;

    if(hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
    {
         Debug.Log("Is a coin");
    }
}
else
{
    pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = noActive;
}
```

or give it a certain component like e.g

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour { }
```

and check for [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.TryGetComponent.html) like

```
if (Physics.Raycast(lastPosition, out hit))
{
    pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = active;

    if(hit.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Coin>(out var hitCoin))
    {
         Debug.Log("Is a coin", hitCoin);
    }
}
else
{
    pointer.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = noActive;
}
```

And yes of course you could when spawning do

```
var coinInstance = Instantiate (coinPrefab, ...);
coinInstance.name = "Coín";
```

and later check for

```
if(hit.gameObject.name == "Coin")
```

but going by string in general is error prone and less efficient

Comment: Can I just change tha name of the clone and access with hit.gameObject.name = "clone name"? Or is a bad habit?

Comment: Using strings is always possible but error prone and quite slow